# C# jumping some textfields like searchboxes

Tags: c#, watin, textfield

I'm just using [watin](/questions/tagged/watin) to fill some textfields but sometimes it writes in the wrong textfield because the textfields name is not clear here's my code

```
IE browser = new IE(site);
browser.TextField(Find.By("type","text")).TypeTextQuickly(username.ToString());
browser.TextField(Find.By("type", //"password")).TypeTextQuickly(pass.ToString());
browser.Button(Find.By("type", "submit")).Click();
```

Comment: What is the website URL?

Comment: no specific website i'm trying for all websites i just want to skip searchboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your HTML code and setup ID´s for your input elements. Then use Find.ById

Comment: Then please attach the html code of the site. Then we can find a "better" / "unique" way to get the elements i guess.

Comment: there are more than two sites i just try to log in with watin

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to see if there is an outer element (such as a `Div`) you can find first, and afterwards get the text fields from that element instead of from the browser variable. That could for instance look like this:

```
Div div = browser.Div(Find.ById("divId"));
//Div div = browser.Div(Find.ByClass("divClass")); // or like this for instance...
TextField text = div.TextField(Find.By("type", "text"));
TextField password = div.TextField(Find.By("type", "password"));
Button submit = div.Button(Find.By("type", "submit"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unclear as to your knowledge of WatiN and testing so I will start from the begginging. First you need to go on the webpage you want to test and (in IE) go to tools -> Developer tools. Click the white arrow in the menu then proceed to click the box you wish to utilize. Once you do this the developer tools will give you the code for the textbox including many ways you can reference it in your code. For example, using dev tools in IE I can automate logging into my gmail like this:

```
IE browser = new IE("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=http://mail.google.com/mail/&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2"); 

browser.TextField(Find.ByID("Email")).TypeText("myemail@email.com");
browser.TextField(Find.ByID("Passwd")).TypeText("mypassword");
browser.Button(Find.ByID("signIn")).Click();
```

There are many Find.By commands so there is no reason you can't acess ANY textfield you wish. You just need the html and to be specific to which one you want to write into. I hope this helps :)